# How to deal with a merge conflict caused by files moved in the target branch

Tags: git, azure-devops

I am very new to git, but I have some changes that I would like to make and there are some merge conflicts. These conflicts come from some files that have been moved in the target branch. How do I deal with these conflicts? The files have only been moved, so the changes that I made still hold, it just tells me that the file was deleted in the target branch. Should I make a new branch off of the updated target branch, and make the changes again?

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more on this. May be sharing the logs or the status can help

Comment: I made a new feature branch. While I was working on it, the develop branch went through some changes where some of the files were moved to new folders. Git does not show that some files were moved, just that there are new files. The pull request says that the files that I have changed are done in a file that is deleted in the develop branch, but all that happened was that they were moved. Hopefully this is a little more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It may help to know that in git, there is no such thing as "moving" a file.

Let's say you move */my/path/file.txt* into a different directory, */my/other/path*. The *whole path* is the name of the file. So what git knows is that there are two files in this story, one named  */my/path/file.txt* and another named */my/other/path/file.txt*. They are not somehow magically associated with one another, as they are in your mind. You call it moved. To git, the first file was deleted and the second file was created.

Now, it is true that *sometimes* when */my/path/file.txt* is deleted and *my/other/path/file.txt* is created, git is able to combine that into the idea of *"renaming"* the file — that is, a file that was in one directory has its pathname changed by now appearing in another directory — but for that to work, they must be identically "the same" file, that is, their contents must be the same.

Otherwise, and in general, when you "move" a file, what git sees is that one file was deleted and another was created. And changing the contents of a file *and* moving it, after one commit but before another, is likely to result in git seeing one file simply disappear (delete) and another as appearing (create).

So, you have in your head a human notion that "The files have only been moved, so the changes that I made still hold", but that is not how git thinks. Git is a computer. What it sees are that in one branch the file named */my/path/file.txt* vanished (because it was "moved", as you suppose). But in the *other* branch the file named */my/path/file.txt* stayed where it was and was edited!

Well, those are two different changes on the *same* file: delete vs. modify. Now git doesn't know what to do.

(Meanwhile, git *also* sees that in the first branch a file named */my/other/path/file.txt* was created, but it does not in any way associate this with either of the two files we just talked about.)

In the end, you have to decide what you want done here. I have to admit that, even as a human, it is unclear to *me* what you think the resolution should be. The situation seems to be that you've really got two files now, the file at */my/other/path/file.txt* created in the first branch, and the file at */my/path/file.txt* deleted in the first branch but edited in the second branch. I cannot imagine how you expect to proceed at this point. You surely do not want both of these files going forward. But where do you want the edited file? Even I don't know the answer to that one.

So you need to answer that question. You probably want it in the new location. So in that case your best bet, it seems to me, is to abort the merge, move  */my/path/file.txt* to */my/other/path/file.txt* in the second branch, and start the merge again.

---

<sub>I would also like to add that conflicts are not, of themselves, a bad thing! All they mean is that git cannot completely generate a merge commit automatically; it doesn't know what you intend. Presumably you do, so you just tell it (by making that part of the merge commit yourself, manually). On the whole, the language of "merge conflict" and "resolve the conflict" is completely misleading; we should think entirely in terms of the positive activity "create (or prepare to create) a merge commit", which either git can do automatically or you and git can do together, cooperatively.</sub>

Comment: Git will—sometimes!—identify (match up) files with different names not just if the content is 100% matching, but even if it's "50% or more matching", so there are more cases where `git merge` will do what the OP wanted than just the exact-match one ... but obviously if he's getting "deleted in ours, modified in theirs" conflicts, it didn't identify the deleted-in-ours file with a separate added-in-ours file to form a renamed-in-ours file-pair.

Comment: When using `git merge` locally, you can supply the match threshold similarity value to override the default "must be at least 50% similar" rule. So the OP might be able to use `git merge -X find-renames=20%` , for instance, to lower the threshold to 20%. Whether this works depends on the degree of similarity of files, and it can backfire and find *too many* renames, sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Before creating the pull request,

1. Merge back the latest develop branch to your feature branch.
2. Then you will see the merge conflicts while merging this. So solve the merge conflicts locally (Better keep the develop's changes and then add your change in the files. Or if you think there is no other change in the develop other than the move, then keep yours and move the files after that. Use your judgement on fixing conflicts).
3. Then create the pull request against the develop.

You cannot always avoid the conflicts. But by merging the develop to your feature branch frequently, you can make your life easiler.